# Ways to avoid using malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

With all recent noise C gets, I read that there are some ways to minimize usage of malloc in C, and that it is a very good practice. I how ever have no idea when or how or what such practices are good. So my question would be, maybe some experienced C programmers could give some examples where one could (or should) write something without malloc, but what would be really non-obvious way for newbie C programmer (and thus said newbie would simply use malloc)? Maybe you have some experiences from factoring out malloc into something else.

P.S. some posts I read were referencing Quake 3 source code and how it avoids use of malloc, so if someone has knowledge of this it would be interesting to know what is done there, since at least for know I would like to avoid digging into quakes code aimlessly. (since well if they avoid using malloc searching for malloc will not give much results I suppose, also code base is most likely not as simple as individual examples could be)

Comment: If you are a newbie there's absolutely no reason to try to avoid using `malloc`. Using custom memory management techniques is quite an advanced topic.

Comment: `With all recent noise C gets...` -- citation needed :)

Comment: Most of the optimizations a mortal C programmer can do with regards to memory management are already implemented in mainstream malloc() implementations. To quote Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Use malloc() unless you **know** it to be the bottleneck in a given code.

Comment: @DevSolar I do not want to do that for optimizations.

Comment: Can we go one full day on SO without that Knuth quote, please?

Comment: @Jon well if one does not look into advanced topics one does not become advanced :)

Comment: @morphles: Of course. I 'm just saying that perhaps a newbie needs more experience first to be able to effectively digest the information.

Comment: @Jon I'm not that much of the newbie, more of coming back to C. While I never was what I would consider advanced C programmer, I still think its about a right time for me to start looking at such things.

Comment: @KingsIndian This very post which is only tagged "C malloc" has around 1.5 views/minute, as one example of "C noise".

Comment: @Nocturno: The day when people no longer make their code worse by trying to avoid bad things. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about totally avoiding `malloc`, but you can certainly reduce it.

The basic concept is a memory pool.  That is a large buffer which you have allocated that you can use for many objects instead of requesting lots of small allocations.

You might use this in a real-world situation where you are sending events into a queue to be processed by another thread.  The event objects might be smallish structures and you really need to avoid making thousands of calls to `malloc` every second.

The answer of course is to draw these event objects from a pool.  If you need to, you can even use parts of your pool buffer to form a list so that you can quickly index memory that has been returned to the pool.  These are generally known as *free-lists*.

You do have to be careful about memory alignment, as you can severely impact performance by having misaligned data.  But you can handle all that with a little maths.

---

Don't freak out about these concepts.  A pool doesn't actually have to be that sophisticated.  Consider this:

```
int ** matrix = malloc( rows * sizeof(int*) );
for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
    matrix[i] = malloc( cols * sizeof(int) );
}
```

I see this all the time, and it's a pet peeve of mine.  Why would you do that, when you can do this:

```
int ** matrix = malloc( rows * sizeof(int*) );
matrix[0] = malloc( rows * cols * sizeof(int) );
for( int i = 1; i < rows; i++ ) {
    matrix[i] = matrix[i-1] + cols;
}
```

And of course, that reduces to this (beware of potential alignment issues in your first row though - I've ignored it here for the sake of clarity)

```
int ** matrix = malloc( rows * sizeof(int*) + rows * cols * sizeof(int) );
matrix[0] = (int*)matrix + rows;
for( int i = 1; i < rows; i++ ) {
    matrix[i] = matrix[i-1] + cols;
}
```

The cool thing about that last example is how easy it is to delete your matrix =)

```
free( matrix );
```

Oh, and zeroing the matrix is just as easy...

```
memset( matrix[0], 0, rows * cols * sizeof(int) );
```

Answer (score 6):

In the scenario where you need small, dynamic sized arrays in local scope, there is  [`alloca()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) which allocates from the stack and doesn't need you to explicitly free the memory (it gets freed when the function returns), and there are [variable length arrays (VLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Length_Array):

```
void meh(int s) {
    float *foo = alloca(s * sizeof(float));
    float frob[s];
} // note: foo and frob are freed upon returning
```

Comment: Ex-Upvoter: Why did you revoke your upvote? Downvoter: Has the reason for the downvote gone?

Comment: While I'm neither... I'll wager a guess that perhaps the downvote was due to the post (sounding like) it was asking for a generic C standard replacement for `malloc` where as `alloca` is machine and compiler dependent. Regardless, I think it deserves a +1 for a unique idea.

Comment: I did not know about alloca, so it is useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike: True, it was a brainfart because I really meant what I have corrected it to now.

Comment: Flexible array members in C99 (or the C90 undefined behavior known as "struct hack") rely on explicit calls to malloc, unlike VLAs.

Comment: @Lundin: That's right. I remove that.

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason for not using `malloc` in some particular cases is probably the fact that it employs a generic, one-size-fits-all approach to memory allocation.

Other approaches, such as memory pools and slab allocation may offer benefits in the case of having well-known allocation needs.

For example, it is much more advantageous for an allocator to assume that the allocated objects will be of a fixed size, or assume that their lifetime will be relatively short. A generic allocator cannot make such assumptions and cannot therefore perform optimally in such scenarios.

The potential benefits can include a decreased memory footprint due to the specialized allocator having a more condensed bookkeeping. A generic allocator most probably holds a larger amount of metadata for each allocated object, whereas an allocator that "knows" in advance what the object's size will be can probably omit it from the metadata.

It can also make a difference in allocation speed - a custom allocator will probably be able to find an empty slot faster.

This is all talking in relatives here, but the questions you should ask before choosing a custom allocation scheme are:

- Do you need to allocate and deallocate a large number of objects having the same size? (Slab allocation)
- Can these objects be disposed at once without the overhead of individual calls? (Memory pools)
- Is there a logical grouping of the individually allocated objects? (Cache aware allocation)

The bottom line is, you have to inspect the allocation needs and patterns of your program carefully, and then decide whether a custom allocation scheme can be beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

If you know all the sizes of arrays, lists, stacks, trees, whatever data structures your program needs beforehand, you can allocate the required memory statically by defining arrays of constant number of elements. Pros: no memory management, no memory fragmentation, fast. Cons: limited use, wasted memory.

You can implement a custom memory allocator on top of `malloc()` or whatever your OS provides, allocate a big chunk of memory once and then carve it up without calling standard `malloc()` functions. Pros: fast. Cons: not quite trivial to implement right.

Another (and a rather perverse) way of avoiding `malloc()` would be to store most of your data in files instead of memory. Pros: virtually none.

You may also use local variables and deep function calls (or explicit recursion) to allocate space for data on the go if you're certain that the program's stack is going to be big enough. Pros: no memory management, easy, fast. Cons: limited use.

As an example of a working midsize project that avoids `malloc()` I can offer my pet project, [Smaller C compiler](http://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC/blob/master/v0100/smlrc.c). It statically allocates a number of arrays and it also allocates small local variables inside recursive functions. Beware, the code hasn't been beautified yet and it's not something small or easy to understand if you're fairly new to programming, C or compilers.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. The next best answer is "Don't use malloc" followed by "use C#/java". Humans suck and make errors all the time, why not use a language which removes the ability to make such errors??

Comment: @rolls Because one size does not fit all.

Answer (score 2):

Allocating a bigger block of memory is usually faster, so my advice would be allocate a big block and then create a memory pool from it. Implement your own functions to "free" memory back to the pool and to allocate memory from it.

Comment: One of the key features of a memory pool is not only being able to free the allocated objects in a symmetric manner as you would do with `malloc`/`free`, but also being able to deallocate the entire pool at once, eliminating the overhead of issuing individual calls to free each object.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I thought I made that clear although I only said it for the allocation, but of course you are right.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons to avoid `malloc` - the biggest one in my mind is that "no malloc, no free" to paraphrase Bob Marley... So, no memory leaks from "forgetting" to call `free`.

And of course, you should always check for `NULL` when allocating memory dynamically. Avoiding this will reduce the amount of code and the complexity of the code.

Unfortunately, the alternative, running out of stack or global variable size is often worse, as it either crashes immediately with no meaningful error message to the user (stackoverflow) or buffer overflow in global variables - checking the boundaries in global variables will avoid this, but what do you do if you detect it? There aren't many choices.

The other part is of course that a call to `malloc` can be substantially expensive, compared to local variables. This is particularly the case when you hit malloc/free calls in "hot-paths" - parts of the code that is called very often. There is also memory overhead in using `malloc` on small memory sections - the overhead from past experience in Visual studio is around 32 bytes of "header" and rounded to 16 or 32 bytes boundaries - so an allocation of 1 byte actually takes up 64 bytes. An allocation of 17 bytes would also take up 64 bytes...

Of course, like ALL engineering/software design, it is not "you MUST NOT USE malloc", but "avoid malloc if there is a simple/suitable alternative". It's wrong to use all global variables that are several times larger than they need to be, just to avoid malloc - but it's equally wrong to call malloc/free for every frame or every object of a graphics drawing loop.

I haven't looked at the code of Quake, but i worked on some code in 3DMark 2000 [I think my name is still in the credits of the product]. That's written in C++, but it avoids using new/delete in the rendering code. It's all done in the setup/teardown of a frame, with very few exceptions.