# How to mapping a 1d array to a 2d array in C?

Tags: c, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I am trying to map the RGB pixels of an image to 2D arrays of R, G, B seperately.
When the image is read the pixels are stored in a 1D array in the form {r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2...}.
The length of array is `3*height*width`. The 2D arrays will be of width X height dimensions

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++) { // length = 3*height*width
    image[i][2] = getc(f); // blue pixel
    image[i][1] = getc(f); // green pixel
    image[i][0] = getc(f); // red pixel

    img[count] = (unsigned char)image[i][0];
    count += 1;

    img[count] = (unsigned char)image[i][1];
    count += 1;

    img[count] = (unsigned char)image[i][2];
    count += 1;

    printf("pixel %d : [%d,%d,%d]\n", i+1, image[i][0], image[i][1], image[i][2]);
}
```

The RGB values are in `img[]`. The 2d arrays are red[][], green[][] and blue[][].

Please help!

Comment: Your code somehow looks as it's already doing it, along with doing the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to reconstruct the colour fields.  Just reverse your function:

```
unsigned char * imgptr = img;

for( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
        red[y][x] = *imgptr++;
        green[y][x] = *imgptr++;
        blue[y][x] = *imgptr++;
    }
}
```

To create your arrays dynamically:

```
unsigned char** CreateColourPlane( int width, int height )
{
    int i;
    unsigned char ** rows;

    const size_t indexSize = height * sizeof(unsigned char*);
    const size_t dataSize = width * height * sizeof(unsigned char);

    // Allocate memory for row index and data segment.  Note, if using C compiler
    // do not cast the return value from malloc.
    rows = (unsigned char**) malloc( indexSize + dataSize );
    if( rows == NULL ) return NULL;

    // Index rows.  Data segment begins after row index array.
    rows[0] = (unsigned char*)rows + height;
    for( i = 1; i < height; i++ ) {
        rows[i] = rows[i-1] + width;
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Then:

```
unsigned char ** red = CreateColourPlane( width, height );
unsigned char ** green = CreateColourPlane( width, height );
unsigned char ** blue = CreateColourPlane( width, height );
```

You can free them easily, but it always pays to wrap the free function if you wrapped the allocator function:

```
void DeleteColourPlane( unsigned char** p )
{
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: `f` in the code snippet is the image file. When I run this I get a stack overflow error!

Comment: You mean you declared each of those 2D arrays on the stack?  Yeah that would probably give you a stack overflow.  I assumed you had already set these up as dynamic arrays.  If not, let me know and I can comment.

Comment: Have a look at my answer for this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14459359/1553090 - the question was closed, but for now it's still available.  In that answer, I've given some tricks for making dynamic 2D arrays less painful to create.

Comment: I did this before the loop but I am getting an error `a value of type void* cannot be usedto initialize an entity of int**`

Comment: Yep, that's the sorta lame way, but it's how most people tend to do it.  You probably want `unsigned char` instead of `int` though!  Read my other examples for how to do it with fewer allocations (and better cache locality).  In fact, you could create all three of your 2D arrays with a single `malloc`.

Comment: Oh right, that probably means you're using a C++ compiler.  I thought you were using C.  In that case, just cast the result of `malloc` to `int**` (or, as I corrected you, `unsigned char**`).

Comment: By the way, if you delete comments that I've replied to, then anyone else who might benefit from this could get rather confused =)